# Edit PDF files programmatically in PHP

Tags: php, pdf

Background info:
I got a project to produce a customised PDF on the fly from a given PDF file using PHP. All I need it to do is to replace strings, e.g. search in "template.pdf" for "{Address}", replace with "Street Name".

I've seen links to fpdf/pdfi/dompdf etc., but can't find any useful example code that I could use :s.
Any help / pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And you control the input PDF file?

Answer (score 4):

fpdf is fantastic, you need to use somthing else to import an exisitng PDF though, See below.

http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/

```
require_once('fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi.php');

$pdf =& new FPDI();

$pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile('TestDoc.pdf');
$tplidx = $pdf->importPage(1, '/MediaBox');

$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->useTemplate($tplidx, 10, 10, 90);

$pdf->Output('newpdf.pdf', 'D');
```

Comment: I've tried that.. cant seem to get it working :| 
got an example you could post?

Comment: Am i meant to be getting deprecated errors with the latest download of fpdi?

"    
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\csllive\fpdi.php on line 88"

Comment: also do i use the php str_replace to replace the text or is there some function in fpdi?

Comment: `$pdf` should probably not be assigned by reference… try replacing `=&` with just `=`

Comment: FPDI is very good but how I can find that string or position were you should write another string in PDF file? FPDI gives answered half but I interest too in a find a text in PDF and replace it or get a text and concatenate another text, or in anthor case to find a way to get coordonate were should place a text.

Answer (score 2):

decided to generate html web page (PHP) then use wkhtmltopdf 
(http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf)

to produce the pdf bit of a work around but less hastle

Answer (score 0):

PDFlib (with the additional PDI) from pdflib.com should be able to do this for you. Admittedly it is pretty pricey, so there may be other options, too :)

Comment: was ideally looking for an opensource/free lib/class